# Apply a drop shadow to only the top border of table rows

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am looking to apply a shadow **only** to the line that goes between the table rows. In the sample below the "red" lines. I don't want the shadow to be applied to the blue borders.

If anyone can fiddle the below snippet to get it to work they would be my hero of the day.

EDIT: I see my snippet has the pointed red line problem. Ideally I actually want a solid non divided red line.

This is the sort of effect I'm looking for:
[image]

```css
.shadow {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.shadow td, .shadow th {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.shadow th {
  border-top: none;
}
.shadow td:last-child, .shadow th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="shadow">
    <tr>
      <th>AH</th>
      <th>BH</th>
      <th>CH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my contribution, hope it helps. :)

```css
.table {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.table tr {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.table th, .table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  border-right:2px solid blue;
}

.table tr:last-child td  {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.table tr td:last-child,
.table tr th:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}

.table tr:last-child {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>AH</th>
      <th>BH</th>
      <th>CH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, this is from one point of view the closest one so far, it's caveats being the 1) The top right and left corners have a faint white pointed background to them. 2) The shadow is only below the red lines and not also above. 3) The shadow is not being applied equally to the bottom read line as the other red lines. This is not really noticeable on the snippet run here but when fiddling with it (adjusting `box-shadow: 0 3px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);` line) the on jsfiddle it is very noticeable.

Comment: I'm marking you answer as correct as even with the caveats mentions above I was able to achieve very good results. (The code I used was somewhat shorter maybe I'll post it as some point) Thanks again

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the following snippet will solve your problem. Let me know if something is not good or you need something explained. Basically I added the box shadow to all td's and th's, and then I just removed them from the last row using the :last-child selector

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, I have updated the adding only

```
.shadow tr:not(:last-child) td, .shadow th{ 
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

which does the trick as well

```css
.shadow {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.shadow td, .shadow th{
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow tr:not(:last-child) td, .shadow th{ 
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.shadow th {
  border-top: none;
}
.shadow td:last-child, .shadow th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="shadow">
    <tr>
      <th>AH</th>
      <th>BH</th>
      <th>CH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: +1.  You could alternatively apply a `:not(:last-child)` selector, to save you from having to undo the style as you describe.

Comment: You are right, I have updated the answer. Not a big difference aI guess but still simpler :)

Comment: Thanks, but there's a noticeable shadow by the blue lines too, also see my comment to Brads answer

Answer (score 1):

You could make it with [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element and [position: absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

```css
.shadow {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.shadow td, .shadow th {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.shadow th {
  border-top: none;
}
.shadow td:last-child, .shadow th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.shadow td:after, .shadow th:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  box-shadow: black 1px 3px 3px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.shadow tr:last-child td:after, .shadow tr:last-child th:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="shadow">
    <tr>
      <th>AH</th>
      <th>BH</th>
      <th>CH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also good, but I still prefer Brads. This one also has the shadow not coming both on top and below the red lines. Also there's something wrong with the red lines that some are coming out slanted at their end.

Comment: I see my original snippet also has the pointed red line problem. Ideally I actually want a solid non divided red line